Proving the existence of a limit cycle
Maybe this is a stupid question but I have the following dynamical system -
$$ x' = -9y(x^2 + 9y^2 + 1) + x(x^2 + 9y^2 -1) $$
$$ y' = x(x^2 + 9y^2 + 1) + y(x^2 + 9y^2 -1) $$
and I have to prove the existence of some limit cycle and look at its stability after transforming this via a “good” transformation.
Polar coordinates turned out to be quite messy (although I might've made an error there) and the only other transformation I thought of was
$$x = cos(t)$$
$$y = \frac{1}{3}sin(t)$$
to get rid of the term on the right, although I got stuck there as well. Is there perhaps something else I should try?

Consider the ellipse defined by the equation $x^2+9y^2=1$. In that ellipse, we have $$x'=-9y(x^2+9y^2+1)\\y'=x(x^2+9y^2+1)$$
The gradient of $f(x,y)=x^2+9y^2-1$, which is orthogonal to the ellipse at every point, is $(2x,18y)$.
Now notice that $$(2x,18y)\cdot (x',y')=18xy(x^2+9y^2+1)-18xy(x^2+9y^2+1)=0$$
This implies that the vector field defining the system is parallel to the ellipse at every point, that is, the ellipse is either an orbit or an union of orbits.
This suggests the change of variables $$x=r\cos(\theta)\\y=\dfrac{r}{3}\sin(\theta)$$
We will have $$r^2=x^2+9y^2\implies rr'=xx'+9yy'\\\tan(\theta)=\dfrac{3y}{x}\implies \dfrac{\theta'}{\cos^2(\theta)}=\dfrac{3y'x-3yx'}{x^2}$$
This gives $$r'=r(r^2-1)\\\theta'=3(r^2+1)$$
Thus, if the initial condition verifies $r<1$ the solution will tend to the origin, and if the initial condition verifies $r>1$ the solution will diverge. This means that the ellipse is an unstable limit cycle.

Ooh, using the gradient this way is a lot more illuminating than my approach was. Thanks a lot, glad to know that I nearly got the transform correctly.
